# Highlight TeX comments in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, tex

I am using Notepad++ as my LaTeX editor but the syntax highlighting for comments are off. I expect the entire line to be the comment colour then I start it with with the percentage sign.

The image illustrates my problem, I expected all contents of line 3,4 and 5 to all be orange.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M3Y9.png

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: has it got something to do with the theme you have selected?

Comment: No, it is the same for all themes.

Comment: Looks like this is a known (open) bug: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2847